# Reverse words of sentence using xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
    <Name> I am Good </Name>
</class>
```

Please transform it into xsl, that provide output "Good am I"

Looking for very soon answer.........

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is a great place to get help with code you are working on. Unfortunately it's not a place to get others to do it for you. Please provide the XSLT that you are having problems with.

Comment: This question is not well-defined. XSLT 1.0 has no concept of a "word" as such; you must specify your own rules as to what constitutes a word. For example, you could use (only) spaces as word delimiters, or spaces along with some punctuation characters, or ...

Comment: @Java Learner: How would you solve it? Is your problem in insufficient knowledge of XSLT or you only don't know how to use XSLT to reach the goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could call a named recursive template to tokenize the text and output the tokens in reverse order. For example:

```
<xsl:template name="reverse-tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, ' ')">
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="reverse-tokenize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This example assumes a space (and only a space) is to be considered a word delimiter.

Example of calling the template:

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
    <xsl:call-template name="reverse-tokenize">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Full demo: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTV